# Cakephp validate function not working

Tags: php, cakephp

here is my model -->

```
<?php 
class Post extends AppModel {
 public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(

                'rule'     => 'alphaNumeric',
                'required' => true,
                'message'  => 'Alphabets and numbers only'
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );


}


?>
```

controller -->

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Post->create();
            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your post.');
            }
        }
    }
```

and view -->

```
<h1>Add Post</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('body', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

How can i get this to work . 
I followed along with cakephp book they have provided at cakephp.org, did exactly the same whatever was mentioned there, then also couldnt get it right

Comment: `$this->request->is('post')` - are you sure it runs into it? maybe its a put? try to use `is(post) || is(put)` in case it is changed for some reason here due to app specific code.

Comment: @mark that's a good point. To the OP, is your data even saving? it could be that the `if $this->request->is('post')` block is never executed

Comment: You need to be more specific. Find out where it stops. Find out what `$this->request->data` contains prior to the save() call. Check for wrongly used callbacks in the (app)model etc.

Comment: can you echo something under condition `$this->Post->save($this->request->data)` to check if it acutally coming here

Comment: added this bit of code ' echo"hello";
                exit;  ' after $this->Post->save($this->request->data) and it worked after hitting save page is just showing white background with hello written.

Comment: @user2366009 can you please share the link which you are referring .. ?

Comment: doing it on local machine !...well did exactly what cakephp developers have mentioned here .. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#data-validation

Comment: your code looks ok so far. what cakephp version?

Comment: then why am i getting error, thought its a noob issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the more verbose array declaration:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'alphaNumeric' => array(
                'rule'     => 'alphaNumeric',
                'required' => true,
                'message'  => 'Alphabets and numbers only'
            ),
        ),
        ...
```

etc (note the deeper array structure) as documented ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html ).

Comment: be more specific. what exactly are you doing. what exactly happens. did you enter "123%56" for example? Note that your current setup might allow empty values submitted since you did not use allowEmpty false. Not sure about that.

Comment: i did leave blank, also sometimes entered !@#$% ie special characters and in both cases post get added !

Comment: use `'allowEmpty' => false` instead of required. the second part is really strange, though.

Comment: tried this too, n it says 'Your post has been saved.' with my title field empty

Answer (score 0):

Before Creating the record just set and validate from controller

```
public function add() 
{
            if ($this->request->is('post')) 
            {
                $this->Post->create();
                $this->Post->set($this->request->data['Post']); // Add this Line
                if ($this->Post->validates()) // Add this Line
                {
                  if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) 
                 {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                 } 
                 else 
                 {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your post.');
                 }
                }
                else 
                 {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your post.');
                 }

            }
  }
```

Comment: thats still crap! you still validate twice (one time more than necessary)

Comment: still not able to validate .

Comment: though cakephp site says when you hot save it automatically calls for validate function !

Comment: Check your Posts table for column title and body.. Is is allow null values, change it to NoT NULL and check

Comment: Please post your sql and tell me the version of cakephp that u using

Comment: sql ? and i am using the latest downloaded yesterday only